# react router browser back button doesn't route to previous page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is my routes.js, when I go to the profile page and after that hit the browser back button it's only change address bar, and didn't route to the Main layout. Please kindly help me to fix that.

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from '../components/Main';
import Home from '../components/Home';
import Profile from '../components/Profile';

import {Router, DefaultRoute, Route} from 'react-router';

export default (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={Main} >
        <Route name="profile" path="profile/:username" handler={Profile} />
        <DefaultRoute handler={Home} />
    </Route>
);
```

this is my main layout

```
var Main = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="main-container">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                    <div className="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2" style={{marginTop: 15}}>
                        <SearchGithub />
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div className="container">
                    <RouteHandler />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: Is an error being thrown in your console when you press the back button by any chance?